# Cloudflare or Apache vhost misconfiguration?

Tags: apache-2.2, cdn, cloudflare

I have setup a website in cloudflare that pointing website3.com to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP address.

In my apache, I have existing website1.com and website2.com vhost (website 1 and 2 are using digital ocean DNS). I created a new vhost for website3.

But when I go to website3.com, It is showing the content of website1. This is probably because when I type the IP in the browser, it lead to website1.

Why is my website3 not using the vhost I have created?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Apache?

Answer (score 1):

You have misconfigured something but with the information provided we can't even guess what it is.

What information you do provide is not consistent with with your (almost content fee) narrative

- website1.com gives me nxdomain - it doesn't exist.
- website2.com gives me 185.53.178.6 - a holding page for a domain registrar.
- website3.com gives me  141.8.230.20 - a holding page for a different registrar.